# The git code for spring security tutorial is not available

Tags: spring, spring-security

When I am reading the following tutorial (https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js), it mentioned the following git repository:
   https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js

However, it seems that this repository contains only two files and others are not available.

Could anybody can recover it ?

Thanks!

Comment: All the links there seem to work for me (at least, they're not 404).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository from the link is the repository with the tutorial content itself. There is no repository with a sample project for that tutorial (since you create the project from scratch in the tutorial, it isn't necessary either).